# Providing custom names for for Metrics in Netflix Servo

Tags: java, jmx, mbeans, netflix, servo

Currently, when I create a JMX Metric and I register it, the metric's namespace seems to be generated as:

```
TYPE.METRIC-NAME.CLASS-NAME.ID
```

So, a counter metric called "numberOfVisitors" in the class VisitorMetric, registered as VistitorServlet looks like:

```
COUNTER.numberOfVisitors.VisitorMetrics.VistitorServlet
```

Ideally, I want it named like:

```
ID.METRIC-NAME
VistitorServlet.numberOfVisitors
```

Even if I could reverse it would be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some playing around, I figured out a work around:

I created a new tag using the config builder with the key "class" this creates a metric called:

COUNTER.[METRIC-NAME].[CLASS-NAME].value

You can also override the COUNTER in the bean name by creating a new Class - unfortunately, Netflix made the concrete Counter classes final, so you can't just extend and override some functionality of the class.